# Can I add custom view on AVPictureInPictureController?

Tags: ios, avplayer

I found an interesting app which pip is not a video but a label:

[image]

I had try add custom layer on AVPlayerLayer, but it not work.

Any idea to achieve it?

Comment: https://github.com/CaiWanFeng/CustomPictureInPicture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the picture-in-picture window in `AVPictureInPictureControllerDelegate` and then add your views:

**Swift:**

```swift
func pictureInPictureControllerWillStartPictureInPicture(_ pictureInPictureController: AVPictureInPictureController) {
    // note this is first window
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first {
        window.addSubview(customView)
        // use autoLayout
        customView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

**Objective-C:**

```objectivec
- (void)pictureInPictureControllerWillStartPictureInPicture:(AVPictureInPictureController *)pictureInPictureController {
    UIWindow *firstWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.firstObject;
    [firstWindow addSubview:self.customView];
    [self.customView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.edges.mas_equalTo(firstWindow);
    }];
}
```

Comment: Is it a valid use case for PiP from Apple standpoint? Would rendering other data (i.e avatars, reactions) during an audio only call risk rejection?

Answer (score 0):

```
let  result =  UIApplication.shared.windows.filter { window in
            
            let type = window.theClassName
            
            return  type == "PGHostedWindow"
        }.first
        
        let title = UILabel()
        title.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 50, width: 300, height: 30)
        title.text = "texttexttexttext"
        title.textColor = .red
        title.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        result!.addSubview(title)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).